# Calculation of 2 points ( 2 sets of coordinates) in perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to calculate the distances between a set of coordinates in the same area. Using the type **distance= sqrt (x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)**. I know that I'm close to make it but I stacked somehow, so I need some help.
  Here is what I wrote:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dumper;
use POSIX;  #gia dekadikous se akairaious

my$x=0;
my$y=0;
my$i=0;
my $flag = 1;
my @temp; #gia na kratisei tin loopa. an den isxei shmainei oti den exoume pinaka
my @proigoumeno;
my @dis;   
my @row;  
#my $counter=0;
my$final;
my $filename = 'myfile.txt';

open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while(<$fh>) {
    @temp = split ' ';
    if( $flag ) {
        @proigoumeno = @temp;
        $flag = 0;
        next;
    }
if( $#temp != $#proigoumeno ) {
    } else {

my @data = map {(($proigoumeno[$_]-$temp[$_])) } 0..$#temp;
    push my@dis, \@data;

foreach $row(@dis){
my$x = $row [$i] ;
my$y = $row [$i+1];
my$final = sqrt(($x**2)+($y**2));
my$ceil=ceil(my$final;) 
         #my$counter =my$counter+1;
say join ' ',$ceil; 
}
}
    }
```

My input file is like this:

```
area1   73070   74098   stop
area1   79689   79934   stop
area2   57000   59336   signal
area2   69391   72882   signal
area3   65205   66473   triangle
area3   66888   68294   triangle
area4   44491   48216   block
area4   269762  273388   block
area5   390882  392312   signal
area5    85172  85501    signal
```

So my desired output I want to be like this:

```
area1   DISTANCE  stop
area2   DISTANCE  signal
area3   DISTANCE  triangle
area4   DISTANCE  block
area5   DISTANCE  signal
```

in which DISTANCE = sqrt(second_line of the second column - the first line of the second column ^2 + the second line of the third column - the first line of the second column ^2) of my input file.

Regarding my desired output:
**a)** I want to print the 1rst column of my file as well as the 4th after the coordinates calculations. Because my level is not good enough to do what I want, I can only print the first column by using a counter at the beginning and print it like this **"say join 'area,$counter'"**,  or to use the command line **|paste** in my output file to add those columns. But inside the code I have no idea how to do that, so If anyone can help on this part I will be thankful  .
**b)** Initially I tested my code by doing only the subtraction of the 2 columns and works perfectly, but when I tried to add the sqrt in the **foreach loop**  I messed up

Comment: The code that I posted is the one that Im trying to run... I know that has some errors at lines 38,42,44 which is resulted by the usage **foreach loop**. My problem started when I added  my$final = sqrt(($x**2)+($y**2)) as a code line in the foreach loop.

Comment: No, the problem is from this jibberish: `ceil(my$final;)`

Comment: Once that it is fixed, you get an error for using `$row` without declaring it. Use `for my $row (...) { ... }`

Comment: Once that it is fixed, you get errors for using non-existent array `@row`. `$row[...]` should be `$row->[...]` (element of the array referenced by the reference in `$row`)

Comment: I don't understand why I got -1 on my question.... I struggled a lot to wrote the code by myself. I m totally new in perl. If was able to wrote the code correctly I wouldn't post any question here.

Comment: @ikegami ... Thanks for replying me. Yes exactly. I Got those mistakes. So as far as I understand I didn't defined the $row correctly.

Comment: @ikagami . thanks again for second comment. Idid the corrections you suggested but I got " Use of uninitialized value $x in exponentiation (**)" Use of uninitialized value $y in exponentiation (**) Doest it mean that I wrote the power at sqrt(($x**2)+($y**2)) wrong??

Comment: Means that `$x` is `undef` rather than a number. The program you posted plus the change I mentioned produces *numerous* warnings, but those aren't among them. I can't comment further on code I haven't seen.

Comment: @ikagami ok, I see!! I will try to figure it out. Thanks again for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the following code sample. I hope that you will learn something new and useful, try to change your programming style.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;

my %points;

my($id,$distance,$name);
my $count = 1;

while(<DATA>){
    my ($id,$x,$y,$name)    = split '\s+';

    $points{$id}{$count} = { x => $x, y => $y };
    $points{$id}{name} = $name;

    $count++;
    $count = 1 if $count > 2;
}

say Dumper(\%points) if $debug;

$~ = 'STDOUT_HEAD';
write;
$~ = 'STDOUT';

foreach $id ( sort keys %points) {
    $name     = $points{$id}{name};
    $distance = distance($points{$id});
    write;
}

$~ = 'STDOUT_BOTTOM';
write;

sub distance {
    my $p = shift;

    my $d = sqrt( ($p->{2}{x} - $p->{1}{x})**2 + ($p->{2}{y} - $p->{1}{y})**2 );

    return $d
}

format STDOUT_HEAD = 
+--------+------------+----------+
| Area   | Distance   | Name     |
+--------+------------+----------+
.

format STDOUT =
| @<<<<< | @######.## | @<<<<<<< |
$id, $distance, $name
.

format STDOUT_BOTTOM =
+--------+------------+----------+
.

__DATA__
area1   73070   74098   stop
area1   79689   79934   stop
area2   57000   59336   signal
area2   69391   72882   signal
area3   65205   66473   triangle
area3   66888   68294   triangle
area4   44491   48216   block
area4   269762  273388   block
area5   390882  392312   signal
area5    85172  85501    signal
```

Output

```
+--------+------------+----------+
| Area   | Distance   | Name     |
+--------+------------+----------+
| area1  |    8824.40 | stop     |
| area2  |   18358.40 | signal   |
| area3  |    2479.62 | triangle |
| area4  |  318511.31 | block    |
| area5  |  433118.45 | signal   |
+--------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: wooow.. Works perfectly!!!. Im sooo excited about the output. Im pressing the enter button on the command prompt again and again just seeing the output running.  I will keep it as template from now.  Thank you soooo much!